# Elegant and fast way without chromatography to remove fluoride ions from water phase without contamination of the polar water soluble product?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, precipitation, salt, halogens

I have a challenging purification routine. I want to remove fluoride from an aqueous solution, my product is a phosphonic acid, which is readly water soluble and an anion.
The anion is about 200 Da in weight and carries two negative charges. It would be nice, if purification could work in the 100mg - 1000 mg range (Basically 100 mg of validated pure substance should be sufficient for most biological and physical testing, but its just nice to have some scaling capacity).
In the solution the anions *-in an ideal scenario-* are my product and the abstracted fluoride (and maybe OH-, depending of the base). The product is very water soluble
and fluoride abstraction is likely to make it even more polar. After the fluoride abstraction, the F- anions need to be removed from solution. I know that you can precipitate fluoride with Ca salts, but are there also other ways to achieve this? I am worried that Ca will also precipitate part of my product out of solution. In previous experiments I saw loss of product because of Ca addition. Some kind of selective catching would be nice. I am wondering if scavenger exist, that are selective for F- only.

If there is no easy approach I would use ionic chromatography, but usually this is kind of time consuming, because you need to mix buffers with specific pH, equilibration takes quite long and than evaporation of water is also a factor, so any hint for streamlining is much appreciated.

Edit: Added more information on product.

Edit2: If you downvote, please be so kind and provide some explanation, otherwise no clearification can be provided.

Comment: What are major or important anions there? // Always include enough relevant details of the question purpose, context or background to make the question clear,  preventing  misunderstanding and need of  clarification.

Comment: The product itself is an anion. Fluoride is an additional anion, when it is abstracted from the product. An additional anion would be OH-,  because you need a base for hydrolysation.

Comment: I have been previously going to suggest anion exchanging resin, but it not applicable. How big is the anion and what are the quantities? What about ion exchanging of gel exclusion chromatography?  // I understand the product may be under business secret restriction, but less you reveal, less satisfying answers you obtain. It is like asking us how the forest can be improved, if you lead there the advisor after nightfall with a band cross eyes. Consider what you can  afford to share and share it, otherwise I am not sure you will receive suitable answers.

Comment: @Poutnik The anion is about 200 Da in weight, carries two negative charges. It would be nice, if purification could Work in the 100mg - 1000 mg. (Basically 100 MG of pure substance should be sufficient for most validation, but its Just nice to have some scaling capacity) I assume you mean its not applicable, because it will Stick to the Resin and is not going off anymore?

Comment: Put additional info rather to the question. Essential is also to know at least the compound class. Questions should not be riddles.

Comment: @Poutinik Added additional information and adjusted some passages language wise to make things more clear.